# When installing neutron ovn from openstack-ansible, ovs will be installed automatically if install_method is set to distro

Tags: openstack, openvswitch, openstack-neutron

We are trying to install openstack through openstack-ansible and configure neutron with ovn.

The installation version was yoga/zed, and ovn was configured by referring to the link below.

yoga : https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible-os_neutron/yoga/app-ovn.html
zed : https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible-os_neutron/zed/app-ovn.html

And the install_method item in the user_variables.yml file is set to distro.

But after installing openstack, ovs is automatically installed and ovn is down

======ovs installation status=======
root@osa-ctrl01:/var/lib/glance# systemctl | grep neutron
**neutron-openvswitch-agent.service**                                                                loaded active running   Openstack Neutron Open vSwitc
neutron-ovs-cleanup.service                                                                      loaded active exited    OpenStack Neutron OVS cleanup
**neutron-server.service**                                                                           loaded active running   neutron-server service
neutron.slice                                                                                    loaded active active    Slice /neutron

========neutron status========
root@11osa-deploy:~# openstack network agent list
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Agent Type                   | Host        | Availability Zone | Alive | State | Binary                     |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+
| efd5ab9b-e70c-4cb8-aac5-e61bd1cf0fe5 | Open vSwitch agent           | 11osa-com01 | None              | XXX   | UP    | neutron-openvswitch-agent  |
| 33e583ef-0cc2-4b7b-b005-c8d6dbc8f630 | OVN Controller Gateway agent | 11osa-com02 |                   | :-)   | UP    | ovn-controller             |
| bbd86693-2a8d-5bc0-83a8-f6401cefe525 | OVN Metadata agent           | 11osa-com02 |                   | :-)   | UP    | neutron-ovn-metadata-agent |
| 2f214e00-ef08-4883-853f-01dc458f4a5b | OVN Controller Gateway agent | 11osa-com01 |                   | **XXX**   | UP    | ovn-controller             |
| b4dbab63-cce0-5ff7-b6be-e88523433a2a | OVN Metadata agent           | 11osa-com01 |                   | **XXX**   | UP    | neutron-ovn-metadata-agent |

I want to configure openstack neutron with ovn.

If install_method is set to distro, we ask if there is a way to not install ovs.

Thank you
your support